# How can i print report directly to printer without dialog

Tags: c#

I saw the Microsoft class below but i can't understand that can anyone help me. My report prints products and these products are called with a store procedure in Sql server database.

```
    public class Demo : IDisposable
    { 
        private int m_currentPageIndex;

        private IList m_streams;

        private DataTable LoadSalesData()
        {
            // Create a new DataSet and read sales data file 
            //    data.xml into the first DataTable.
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataSet.ReadXml(@"..\..\data.xml");
            return dataSet.Tables[0];
        }
        // Routine to provide to the report renderer, in order to
        //    save an image for each page of the report.
        private Stream CreateStream(string name,
          string fileNameExtension, Encoding encoding,
          string mimeType, bool willSeek)
        {
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
            m_streams.Add(stream);
            return stream;
        }
        // Export the given report as an EMF (Enhanced Metafile) file.
        private void Export(LocalReport report)
        {
            string deviceInfo =
              @"<DeviceInfo>
                    <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
                    <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>
                    <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>
                    <MarginTop>0.25in</MarginTop>
                    <MarginLeft>0.25in</MarginLeft>
                    <MarginRight>0.25in</MarginRight>
                    <MarginBottom>0.25in</MarginBottom>
                </DeviceInfo>";
            Warning[] warnings;
            m_streams = new List<Stream>();
            report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream,
               out warnings);
            foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
                stream.Position = 0;
        }
        // Handler for PrintPageEvents
        private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
        {
            Metafile pageImage = new
               Metafile(m_streams[m_currentPageIndex]);

            // Adjust rectangular area with printer margins.
            Rectangle adjustedRect = new Rectangle(
                ev.PageBounds.Left - (int)ev.PageSettings.HardMarginX,
                ev.PageBounds.Top - (int)ev.PageSettings.HardMarginY,
                ev.PageBounds.Width,
                ev.PageBounds.Height);

            // Draw a white background for the report
            ev.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect);

            // Draw the report content
            ev.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, adjustedRect);

            // Prepare for the next page. Make sure we haven't hit the end.
            m_currentPageIndex++;
            ev.HasMorePages = (m_currentPageIndex < m_streams.Count);
        }

        private void Print()
        {
            if (m_streams == null || m_streams.Count == 0)
                throw new Exception("Error: no stream to print.");
            PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
            if (!printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error: cannot find the default printer.");
            }
            else
            {
                printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
                m_currentPageIndex = 0;
                printDoc.Print();
            }
        }
        // Create a local report for Report.rdlc, load the data,
        //    export the report to an .emf file, and print it.
        private void Run()
        {
            LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
            report.ReportPath = @"..\..\Report.rdlc";
            report.DataSources.Add(
               new ReportDataSource("Sales", LoadSalesData()));
            Export(report);
            Print();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (m_streams != null)
            {
                foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
                    stream.Close();
                m_streams = null;
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Demo demo = new Demo())
            {
                demo.Run();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What part you do not understand and what do you expect from us? We cannot explain every single line. So please be more specific. To me this demo code shows all the steps you need. It shows the step involved so you should be able to use this for your code as a starting point.

Comment: @PeterBons , what is stream

Comment: The report renders (writes) it content to a memory stream as an image. This line does that: `report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream,
               out warnings);
            `. This stream is used by the `PrintPage` method.

Comment: @PeterBons i understood now , where do i have to write the code in the form where i added report viewer or in the form where i have the button to press Print